# How can I implement event acessors with DynamicObject in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, c#-4.0

I am trying to implement a generic Wrapper-Class for Qt's class system using C#'s DynamicObject. However, I want to write the following code:

```
dynamic obj = new SomeWrapperClass(....); // This extends DynamicObject
obj.OnMyEvent += (Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("DO something!"));
```

The above is valid code according to VS2010 (the explicit cast to Action is required), but how exactly do i "catch" that statement using DynamicObject's methods?

I tried implementing TryGetMember() and it gets called for the statement, but I have no idea what I have to return to make it work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflector is your friend on this one. The code generated for your second line looks something like this (approximately):

```
if(Binder.IsEvent("OnMyEvent", typeof(SomeWrapperClass)))
{
    Binder.InvokeMember("add_OnMyEvent", obj, myAction);
}
else
{
    var e = Binder.GetMember("OnMyEvent", obj);
    var ae = Binder.BinaryOperation(ExpressionType.AddAssign, e, myAction);
    Binder.SetMember("OnMyEvent", obj, ae);
}
```

If you can't use a real event for `OnMyEvent` (in which case you can lean on the default `DynamicObject` implementation), then you'll need to return something that implements `AddAssign` returning something like a multicast delegate. I'd suggest the former, if possible...

For fun, here's a hackish example that dynamically binds OnMyEvent to OnMyOtherEvent:

```
public class SomeWrapperClass : DynamicObject
{
    public event Action OnMyOtherEvent;

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "OnMyEvent")
        {
            result = OnMyOtherEvent;
            return true;
        }
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "OnMyEvent" && value is Action)
        {
            OnMyOtherEvent = (Action)value;
            return true;
        }
        return TrySetMember(binder, value);
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        if (OnMyOtherEvent != null)
            OnMyOtherEvent();
    }

    private static void TestEventHandling()
    {
        dynamic obj = new SomeWrapperClass(); // This extends DynamicObject
        obj.OnMyEvent += (Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("DO something!"));
        obj.Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a LOT for the hint about just looking at the IL it generates (well or a rather high-level representation). What I find quite interesting is how it handles the return value of GetMember. Couldn't I just use a static "mock" event to return from TryGetMember for all my events, then do the actual binding in TryInvokeMember? (for add_XYZEvent)?

Comment: That's what I would try, yes. I have no idea if it would work well, but if you get it figured out please share. :)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke your `Action` with reflection:

```
dynamic o = new SomeWrapperClass();
o.OnMyEvent += (Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("DO something!"));
var a = typeof(SomeWrapperClass).GetField("OnMyEvent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
(a.GetValue(o) as Action).Invoke();
```

Output:
DO something!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing events with delegates. Events are effectively delegates, but you cannot use the 'add' and 'remove' accessors with delegates - however the += and -= works the same with both.

```
obj.OnMyEvent += (Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("DO something!"));
```

This is basically adding a target to the invocation list of a delegate, so that delegate must have a similar type (in this case a parameterless Action delegate).

The suggested implementation is below:

```
private Action actiondelegate = (Action)(() => {});

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
    if (binder.Name == "OnMyEvent")
    {
        result = actiondelegate;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that you need an empty Action in your Action delegate - this is because if it is null the `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` wont work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I read all the answers and I really wanted to avoid the "`TryGetMember`" and "`TrySetMember`" solutions since it feels very unnatural.
(You'd be able to save the event in a variable, or write stuff like `var x = dynObj.MyEvent + MyAction;` without compile time or runtime errors.)

Looking in dahlbyk's Answer I saw there *is a check* for "`IsEvent`" in the decompiled code and I wanted that to just return `true`.

I'll try to keep it short - I *did* managed to make it work with a very very very hackish way (more then "regular" reflection hackish level!)

No methods from `DynamicObject`'s API are called for this check except `GetMetaObject`. I tried overriding it but I couldn't get any positive results. Maybe someone smarter can prove I overdid it.

Without any other options I resorted the wrost way to solve this: reversing the inner working of .NET, using a runtime patcher and a lot of reflection.

The solution is hijacking the return value of a function called `BindIsEvent` in the type `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder` in the assembly `Microsoft.CSharp`.
It replaces its result from "false" to "true" when my specific target (`SomeWrapperClass`) and event name (`"OnMyEvent"`) are provided.
(It's not really returning a `bool`, it returns an ugly internal class called `EXPR` which most of the reflection code is trying to create).
[Reference source code provided by Microsoft here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/Microsoft.CSharp/Microsoft/CSharp/RuntimeBinder.cs#L1954)

My solution uses a lot of refletion so I wrote some helper functions (`Steal`, etc...)

**For this solution you need to get the [Harmony patching library from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lib.Harmony/).**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using static DynamicEventsTest.ReflectionTricks;

namespace DynamicEventsTest
{
    public static class ReflectionTricks
    {
        private static BindingFlags ALL = (BindingFlags)0xffff;
        public static T Steal<T>(Type t, object o, string member) =>
                    (T)(t.GetFields(ALL).SingleOrDefault(fld => fld.Name == member)?.GetValue(o) ??
                    t.GetProperties(ALL).SingleOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == member)?.GetValue(o) ??
                    (t.GetMethods(ALL).Where(mth => mth.Name == member).Skip(1).Any() ?
                        (object)(t.GetMethods(ALL).Where(mth => mth.Name == member).ToArray()) : // Several overloads
                        t.GetMethods(ALL).SingleOrDefault(mth => mth.Name == member))); // Just a single overload (or null)
        public static T Steal<T>(object o, string member) => Steal<T>(o.GetType(), o, member);
        public static T Steal<T>(Type o, string member) => Steal<T>(o, null, member);
        public static T DeepSteal<T>(object o, string pathToInnerMember)
        {
            if (pathToInnerMember.Contains("."))
            {
                string rest = pathToInnerMember.Substring(0, pathToInnerMember.LastIndexOf('.'));
                pathToInnerMember = pathToInnerMember.Substring(pathToInnerMember.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                o = DeepSteal<object>(o, rest);
            }
            return Steal<T>(o, pathToInnerMember);
        }

        public static MethodInfo Overload(this MethodInfo[] overloads, params Type[] types) =>
            overloads.SingleOrDefault(
                mi => mi.GetParameters().Length == types.Length &&
                        mi.GetParameters().Zip(types, (pi, expectedType) => pi.ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(expectedType)).All(b => b));
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void PostHook(object __instance, object __0, object __1, object __2, ref object __result)
        {
            string name = Steal<string>(__0, "Name");
            // Debug print. You can delete this.
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to access: " + name);
            Array array = (Array)__1;
            object wrappedTarget = array.GetValue(0);
            object target = Steal<object>(wrappedTarget, "Value");

            // Make sure that target object and event name match what we want to patch
            if (target is SomeWrapperClass && name == "OnMyEvent")
            {
                Type[] types = __instance.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes();

                // Only touch this
                bool THE_ACTUAL_BOOLEAN_RESULT = true;

                // Don't touch this
                //
                Type PredefinedType = types.Single(t => t.Name.EndsWith("PredefinedType"));
                var PT_BOOL = Steal<object>(PredefinedType, "PT_BOOL");
                Type ConstValFactoryType = types.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ConstValFactory"));
                MethodInfo GetBool = Steal<MethodInfo>(ConstValFactoryType, "GetBool");
                var CONSTVAL = GetBool.Invoke(null, new object[1] { THE_ACTUAL_BOOLEAN_RESULT });
                object SymbolLoader = Steal<object>(__instance, "SymbolLoader");
                var boolType = Steal<MethodInfo[]>(SymbolLoader, "GetReqPredefType").Overload(PredefinedType)
                    .Invoke(SymbolLoader, new object[1] { PT_BOOL });
                object m_exprFactory = Steal<object>(__instance, "m_exprFactory");
                MethodInfo CreateConstant = Steal<MethodInfo[]>(m_exprFactory, "CreateConstant").Overload(boolType.GetType(), CONSTVAL.GetType());
                var replacementResults = CreateConstant.Invoke(m_exprFactory, new object[2] { boolType, CONSTVAL });
                //
                // End

                // Debug prints to show we succeeded. You can Remove those.
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Original Results: " + __result);
                bool bRes = DeepSteal<bool>(__result, "val.boolVal");
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Converted to bool: " + bRes);
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Replacement Results: " + replacementResults);
                bRes = DeepSteal<bool>(replacementResults, "val.boolVal");
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Converted to bool: " + bRes);

                // Actually override the results
                __result = replacementResults;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve the method "RuntimeBinder.BindIsEvent"
            AppDomain d = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            Assembly microsoftCSharpAssembly = d.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Microsoft.CSharp")).Single();
            Type[] types = microsoftCSharpAssembly.GetTypes();
            var RuntimeBinder = types.Single(yy => yy.Name.EndsWith("RuntimeBinder"));
            MethodInfo method = Steal<MethodInfo>(RuntimeBinder, "BindIsEvent");

            // Setup Harmony patching enviroment
            HarmonyLib.Harmony harmony = new HarmonyLib.Harmony("some.string");
            MethodInfo postHookMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("PostHook", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Do the hooking
            harmony.Patch(method, postfix: new HarmonyLib.HarmonyMethod(postHookMethod));

            dynamic obj = new SomeWrapperClass();
            obj.OnMyEvent += (Action)MyEventHandler; // This will Trigger "TryInvokeMember" for "add_OnMyEvent" !
        }

        public static void MyEventHandler()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on .NET framwork 4.8, Your mileage may vary (MS can change those internal APIs in any version of .NET).