# How to solve case insensitive conflict name in COM while I using a case sensitive language

Tags: c#, com, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, wmp

This question is an extension of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630656/how-to-attach-event-to-dynamic-object-or-com-object).

In the same case, I created a instance of WMP ActiveX by its `ProgID`.

```
protected const string WMP_PROG_ID = "WMPlayer.OCX.7";

private dynamic _wmp;

protected virtual bool init(){
    try{
        _wmp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(WMP_PROG_ID));
    }
    catch{ return false; }
    return connectEvent();
}
```

According the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564034.aspx) document, there are an `Error` event and an `error` property in WMPlayer object.
So, I try to attach events like this way.

```
protected bool connectEvent(){
    try{
        _wmp.PlayStateChange += new StateHandler(_wmp_PlayStateChange);
        //_wmp.Error += new Action(_wmp_ErrorEvent);
    }
    catch { return false; }
    return true;
}

protected void _wmp_PlayStateChange(WMPlayerState state){
    //do something I like
}

protected void _wmp_ErrorEvent(){
    //do some error handling
}
```

If I keep `//_wmp.Error += new Action(_wmp_ErrorEvent)` commented,
there's no compile error and `PlayStateChange` works pretty good.

However, if I remove the comment mark, there's a runtime exception.
`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: can not apply operator "+=" between 'System.__ComObject' and 'System.Action'`

It seems the two "error" are conflicted because COM is case insensitive. How can I solve it?
My goal is that attach to "Error" event without using AxWindowsMediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a very similar problem as you but mine was with `Size`. The strongly typed ActiveX control redefined `Size` so I needed to cast it back to `Control` when the forms designer wanted to size the control on my form.

```
((Control)this.axLEAD1).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(298, 240);
```

If you can get a strongly typed class for the com object (by adding a reference or using [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) you may be able to cast to the strongly typed com object instead of `__ComObject` and have it use the correct method.

Comment: Thanks for idea, I tried to use tlbimp convert wmp.dll, and disassemble it. However, there's only `Error` property but no `error` event. I guess the conversion of MS tool do not handle this conflict problem, either.